# UIView .animate not working vs .animateKeyframes

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I am trying to figure out why `UIView.animate` does not work as intended.

I know with `UIView.animateKeyframes` I can chain multiple types of animations together, but in this instance I am doing just one animation `transform` from the current size to `0.0`.

The spinner image is already spinning using `CABasicAnimation` prior to this transform using:

```
let spinAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
            spinAnimation.toValue = .pi * 2.0 // 360º spin
            spinAnimation.duration = 1.4
            spinAnimation.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude // Repeat forever in loops.
            spinAnimation.isCumulative = true
            spinAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

            self.spinnerImageView.layer.add(spinAnimation, forKey: self.spinnerAnimationKey)
```

**UIView KeyFrame Animation**

```
 UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: Constants.AnimationDuration.standard, delay: 0.0, options: .calculationModeLinear, animations: {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            self.spinner.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        })
    }) { (_) in
        super.endRefreshing()
    }
```

**UIView Animation**

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.spinner.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    }) { (_) in
        super.endRefreshing()
    }
```

The keyframe animation works as intended where it shows the animating image shrink to `0.0`, but the standard animate just causes the image to disappear. Shouldn't they act in the same way or is it because the image already has a CABasicAnimation layer that is causing the `animate` to not work properly? I would prefer to use `.animate` since I am only doing a transformation.

Comment: Why are you doing a `self.spinner.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity` inside the `UIView.nimate`? You either do the `scaleX` or you do bring the UIViews view matrix back to it's `identity`. `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.0, y: 0.0)` will scale the view to 0 x and 0 y essentially hiding it, the identity, brings it back to it's original view matrix from the previous view matrix state.

Comment: @Annjawn you are right. However, `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.0, y: 0.0)` is not working in `UIView.animate`